# Node.js + Postgres multiple query and json object

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I've those tables:
Car [idcar, name, brand, color]
Optional [idoptional, idcar, name]

I need execut this tree queries and return an object like this:

```
[
  {  idcar: '1', 
     name: 'ASTRA', 
     surname: 'OPEL', 
     color: 'red', 
     optional : [
       { idoptional: '12', name: 'LED Lights' }, {idoptional: '13', name: 'retrocamera'}
     ]
  },
  {  idcar: '2', 
     name: 'FIAT', 
     surname: 'PUNTO', 
     color: 'white', 
     optional : [
       { idoptional: '16', name: 'SportPack' }, {idoptional: '13', name: 'retrocamera'}
     ]
  } 
]
```

I've this code:

```
const getCars = (request, response) => {
   pool.query('SELECT * FROM cars', (error, results) => {
     if (error) {
       throw error
     }
     response.status(200).json(results.rows)
   })
}
```

and

```
const getOptionals = (request, response) => {
const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM optionals WHERE idcar= $1', [id], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
       throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
}
```

But i've two separated json... i need only one object

Answer (score 0):

(Postgres 9.4+ solution)

It looks like what you need is

1. a join of the cars and optionals table
2. the use of a [postgres aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-aggregate.html).

Here is a working example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=49c6d9707b2e9f93b79abdebcfc6ba19

Comment: i've postgres 9.0 :(

Comment: In that case your best bet might be to do something like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=6358001b84438f6e35085ea1affc808d, then iterate  through the result in node (probably using `reduce`) to create the desired final array